# Nginx 404 Report

Tags: nginx, reporting, http-status-code-404

I'm looking for some means of reporting 404 errors to my client for a site we've inherited.

404s in the application (Django) are handled by Sentry, and that's working brilliantly, but this is for things which don't hit Django (eg, links to static PDFs).

I'm thinking I can write something to grep the Nginx log, showing me a list of 404 URLs, with frequency maybe.

I think something like AWStats is a bit overkill for this.

Can anyone point me at anything?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could do something like:

(nginx conf)

```
error_page 404 = /report_404.html;
```

And then create a django view for `report_404.html` that logs an entry to sentry.